# Select cells that fit in the range of the counter and concatenate what is selected from the range

Tags: vba, concatenation, counter

I've been working on a Macro that i need to copy, concatenate what has been selected through the counter. e.g. is below

[excel snapshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NARvj.png)

so what i want to do is set a count in column c from 1 to "infinite" because each worksheet varies to go up to 10 or hundreds and when the counter hits a value of 1 again to stop concatenate column D what is in the range from 1 to "the last digit it stopped before hitting 1 again" and paste it on a different sheet. I know little to nothing on VBA but I understand the copy and paste to different sheet part. I'm just stuck on the counter and the concatenate part. Here is the code i have so far(i edited it to resemble the example for better reference)

```
'select counter/concatenate
Sheets(1).Select
Columns("C").EntireColumn
 Do
 Columns("C").Count
 For i = 1 To 9999
 Loop While (i <= 1)
 If i = 1 Then
 select.columns("D")
```

after the count is where i am stuck. this count is what I've come up with looking at different variations of counters.

Comment: I just ran it to check the counter and the counter doesn't work. says "loop without do", but i do have a "do"

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand what you're wanting to do based on your snapshot.
The script should go from C1:C5, when it hits C6 which is a new value 1, concatenate D1:D5 and put it on another sheet (abcde).

Comment: yup. exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you Forget about column and use just one cell for easier understanding. A cell is a reference that allows you to refer to any other cells on the sheet by using Offsets. You may use two Loops, the outer one crawling the columns, the inner one working downward until it finds 1

```
   Dim i As Long   ' note that in VBA integer Overflows at 65535 rows
   Dim s As String

   Set aCell = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("D1")
   While aCell.Column < 255
      i = 0
      s = ""
      While Not aCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = 1
         s = s & aCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
      Wend
 ' paste s somewhere by using range.value = s
      Set aCell = aCell.Offset(0, 1)
   Wend
```

By specifying the workbook and worksheet before the range, you may refer to the proper cell without being dependent on the active worksheet or range.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (not tested):

```
   Dim s As String, firstAddr as String
   Dim f as range, iniCell As Range

   With Worksheet("MySheet") '<--| change "MySheet" to your actual sheet name
       With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
           Set f = .Find(What:=1, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
           If Not f Is Nothing Then
               firstAddr = f.Address
               Set iniCell = f
               Set f = FindNext(f)
               Do While f.Address <> firstAddr
                   s = s & Join(Range(iniCell, f.Offset(-1)).Offset(, 1), "")

                   ' here code to paste s somewhere

                   Set iniCell = f
                   Set f = FindNext(f)
               Loop 
           End If
       End With
   End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I actually tested, using some random data in columns C and D.

You'll have to modify a little to get exactly where you want the data to go, but should get you in the right direction.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'This will get an accurate last row

    c = 1

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        s = s & ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value 'Build the string
        If ws1.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = 1 Or ws1.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = "" Then
            ws2.Cells(c, 1).Value = s
            s = ""
            c = c + 1
        'If the next cell to check is 1 or blank, then copy the values to the next cell in order on sheet2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Walking through it, `lastRow` is set using the last row in the sheet with a value in it.  Then, `c` is set to one, although you could set this to the last available row in `ws2` using the same process.  After that it just steps through the rows from `1 To LastRow` building strings and transferring the value to `ws2` when it's about to hit a 1.